# iOS to S3 direct upload with Rails API + ActiveStorage

Tags: amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I have an API with a file upload endpoint using Rails and ActiveStorage with S3 as the fileserver. I would like to upload directly to S3 from my client app but the code provided in the Active Storage docs only shows that using Javascript https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

Since i am sending a POST request with the file to the Rails API directly, there is no place i can run JS.

Is there a way with Rails API only apps to use direct upload?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve a similar issue I've followed the approach proposed in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

The simple concept is that for each file that I want to upload, I do the following workflow:

1. Request my server for a S3 presigned_url/public url pair
2. Send the file via post/put (depending on the presigned you choose) to S3
3. Once I get the 200 (OK) from the S3 upload, I send a new request to my server with the resource that i'm trying to update and in the params for this resource i include the public URL.

e.g:

1. `GET myserver.com/api/signed_url?filename=<safe_file_name>`

1.1. Replies with

`{
  presigned_url: "https://bucket-name.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/1bb275c5-0199-41fe-ac40-133601f5efb0?x-amz-acl=public-read...",
  public_url: "https://bucket-name.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/1bb275c5-0199-41fe-ac40-133601f5efb0"
}`

2. `PUT <presigned_url>, data: <file_to_upload>, cache: false, processData: false`

2.1. Wait for 200 (OK) from S3 direct upload

3. `POST myserver.com/api/document, data: { name: 'new file', document_url: <public_url> }`